# A botched update where clause almost as bad as bobby tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I was performing an update on a production mysql database and to my surprise I updated the entire table because of a botched where clause.

My query looked like:

```
update users where userid-123
```

Instead of using an equal sign I used a dash character, and the entire table was updated.

Why exactly did this even run?  Shouldn't it have been an error?

I guess mysql translated it as:

```
update users where true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html):

> MySQL evaluates any nonzero, non-NULL value to TRUE.

So what happened here is `userid-123` resulted in a subtraction operation, the result of which would be interpreted as true for all rows with `userid` other than NULL and 123.